# A recursive Python function to get a list all files in a series of nested folders

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to write a Python def function to recursively scan a series of nested folders and return a list of the found file names.  It seems to be working (kind of) but is finding too many files.  I know the answer is about 2100 files but it is returning over 7000.  This is my first foray into recursive programming.  Here is my code, what am I doing wrong? Thanks...RDK

ps....I'm testing it on Windows 10, but eventually want run it also on a Linux computer...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python3 program to list files in nested folders
import os
def Files_Dirs(filelist,rootdir):
    print("filelist length is ",len(filelist))
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
# dirs and files are the files and directories found in "rootdir"
        for file in files:
#append the file name to the list
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))
        print("Lenght of myfilelist is ", len(filelist))
        for dir in dirs:
# work through the sub directories
            print("next dir is " + rootdir + "/" + dir)
            filelist = Files_Dirs(filelist, rootdir + "/" + dir)
    return filelist

rootdir = 'D:/my/images'
images=[]
OutPrint = open('c:/temp/filenamefixed.txt','w')
count=0
filelist = []
filelist=Files_Dirs(filelist,rootdir)
print ("Number of file found was ", len(filelist))
count=0
for x in filelist:
    count=count+1
    OutPrint.write(x + "\n")
print ("Number of file iterated was ", count)
OutPrint.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not completely understand the information being returned by os.walk(path)!

My goal was a list of all files in the path, which was a series of multiple nested folders, several levels deep.  The series of 3-tuples generated by os.walk provides all of that, provided one "walks" all of the directories and files for EACH iteration of 3-tuples.  Recursive calls are not needed.

```
rootdir = "d:/mymages/images"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    print("root = ",root)
    for dir in dirs:
        print("Directory = ",dir)
    for file in files:
        count=count+1
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))
print("Folder walk count is ",count)
count=0
for x in filelist:
    count=count+1
print ("Number of file iterated was ", count)
```